# Show that all $\vec{v}$ in matrix $B$ is also in matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I am given a two matrixes $A$ and $B$ where $B$ is a square $n\times n$ matrix while $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. with $m=7$ and $n=6$ I want to show that all the vectors in matrix $A$ is also in matrix $B$. Matrix $A$ has six rows and 7 columns, while for matrix $B$ it has  six rows and columns. How do I check that?

My thought was that is to check the column rank of matrix $A$, if it has column rank $6$ then we have $A=\mathbb{R}^6$ and $B$ being a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^6$ will be a subspace of $A$ meaning all vectors in $B$ is in $A$. But I came to conclusion that the column rank of $A$ is $4$ while $B$ only had $3$. Now what do I do now? Do I need to find a basis for both col $A$ and col $B$ and check if the basis vector  of col$B$ can be written in terms of basis vector of col$A$?

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 3 & 1 & -3& 11&2&5\\3&3&2&-3&10&3&9\\4&3&0&2&-3&9&4\\2&-1&-1&1&-3&2&-1\\3&-1&3&0&-4&2&12\\1&0&4&3&-13&4&13\end{pmatrix}$$ while $$B=\begin{pmatrix}4&-3&7&5&6&13\\ 4&-1&5&9&12&14\\7&3&4&8&18&1\\2&3&-1&9&14&5\\-1&7&-8&14&20&4\\-3&8&-11&1&6&-17\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: the left kernel of $A$ is the orthogonal of the space $col(A)$, so col(B) is inside col(A) if and only if the left kernel of $A$ is inside the left kernel of B

Comment: left kernel? what is that exactly

Comment: ah nvm i get it

Comment: would it suffice to check if col A is linearly independet to determine if all of col B is in col A?